# What are the way i can keep track of min/call by each of customer

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call

Our usecase in simplified manner:
1) Custom come to our website
2) he see a list of phone numbers
3) he click on a phone number to call.

For above i am reading 
https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/client/outgoing-calls

Our plan is to give this call functionality as a added feature where we will charge end customer what twilio charges us.

Now i need to keep trace of number of call/min each of our customer used. so that i can charge him for the same.

What are the way i can keep track of min/call by each of our customer?

Edit:
Is there any api/webhock that can be used to keep track of when a particular call started and ended so that we can save the duration of call and charge for the same.

Comment: The question is quite broad and you provide no code or output. You're not even stating which language you're using or am I overlooking something? (I assume it's Java because of the twilio link but who knows?) You got to give people something to work with if you want meaningful advice.

Comment: @jDo this question doesnt require a specific langauge or code.. the question is,  is there something which twilio provide to track it. i have added some extra info

Comment: Good. Simply by writing *"(...)  is there something which **twilio** provide to track it."*, you narrow down the scope considerably. Apparently, you're looking for some features in the twilio API if they exists. Without that, you could've been asking for some SQL database solution, a Java function or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Good news! There are a couple of ways for you to find out this information.

Firstly, you can set a StatusCallback URL that receives webhook information about calls. You can either set this on the level of the number, using the [phone numbers section of the Twilio portal](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/incoming). Or you can [set a `StatusCallback` parameter when you create calls using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post-parameters-optional). Or you can [set a `StatusCallback` attribute when creating calls using the `<Number>` noun in TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes-status-callback).

Either way you set the callback, you will get a webhook back to the URL you set when the call is over. That [webhook will include a `CallDuration` parameter with the duration of the call in seconds](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request#asynchronous).

For more accurate price reporting, you can actually query the REST API. [Call instance resources have a `Price` property](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#instance). The only drawback here is that the `Price` property may not immediately be available. So you may need to schedule jobs to check for the price after a call is complete.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: this is great.. will try it out.. also there is concept of subaccounts which is also great but has a limit of 1000

Comment: It does have a limit, but if you think you will need more then you should talk to sales about getting that limit lifted.